# JSOM: get_lists() doesn't retrieve "Shared Documents" document library

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I'm developing Sharepoint Add-ins using the Visual Studio 2015 environment. I'm using the JavaScript Object Model to develop this add-in.

I want to get list of files from the Sharepoint website where this add-in will run.

When I run the add-in for testing out my code, it gets automatically hosted on a subdomain with naming convention `<tenancy_name>-<autogenerated_number>`

Note that

1. Tenancy name is suffixed with some auto-generated number and
2. The URI has the development site name followed by addin name.

In my project properties, the Site URL property is set to a URL with subdomain `<tenancy_name>`

When I browse to documents from web UI, the URL I see has `<tenancy_name>` as subdomain. There is no addin name that appears in URI here (for obvious reasons). The URI indicates existance of `Shared Documents` document library: `/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`.

Note that Shared Documents is reachable in such a URL that hasn't got auto-generated number suffixed to tenancy name in subdomain.

I've written a JavaScript code that first retrieves all lists from the website. I wanted to check whether "Shared Documents" appears in that list. But it seems "Shared Documents" doesn't appear in the lists I retrieve.

Please find below my JavaScript code.

```
// Function to execute basic operations.

function execOperation() {

    //ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getAllFiles, "sp.js");//not prefered way
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAllFiles);//more prefered way

}
function getAllFiles() {
    try {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        alert("Context URL: " + clientContext.get_url());//Gives /sites/&lt;development_site&gt;/&lt;addin_name&gt;
        this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

        this.allLists = this.oWebsite.get_lists();

        clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
        clientContext.load(this.allLists);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.successHandler),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.errorHandler)
            );
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("message:" + e.message);
    }
    alert("successful completion");

}

function successHandler(sender, args) {
    $('#message').text('success ');
    alert('Title: ' + this.oWebsite.get_title() +
' Description: ' + this.oWebsite.get_description()
+ " url: " + this.oWebsite.get_url());//Gives entire url with &lt;tenancy_name&gt;-&lt;autogenerated_number&gt; in subdomain
    var listInfo = '';
    var listEnumerator = this.allLists.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' +
            oList.get_created().toString() + '\n';
    }
    alert(listInfo);//Doesn't give "Shared Documents" here

}

function errorHandler() {
    //$('#message').text('error ');
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Failure";
}
```

My question is

1. Is my understanding correct about fact that `Shared Documents` is accessible only if `website.geturl()` returns subdomain as simple `<tenancy_name>` and not as `<tenancy_name>-<autogenerated_number>`?
2. Is it possible to access `Shared Documents` irrespective of what URL gets generated from `website.get_url()`?

What is missing in my code and understanding relationship between URL viz Document Library and lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
```

gives you the web `https://<tenancy_name>-<autogenerated_number>.sharepoint.com/sites/<development_site>/<addin_name>`, so the code is actually querying the add-in web, not `https://<tenancy_name>.sharepoint.com/sites/<development_site>/` (the host site), that's why it cannot display `Shared Documents`.

In order to query host site, we need `SP.AppContextSite`.

```
var hostSiteUrl = 'host site url' // This value is passed to your add-in as a url parameter called SPHostUrl, you can get it from document.URL
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostSiteUrl);
var web = appContextSite.get_web(); // This is the web object points to host site
var lists = web.get_lists();

clientContext.load(lists);
...
```

And don't forget to set 'Read' permission for 'Web' scope in Visual Studio.

Comment: Didn't know how to set read permission for web scope. Got solution here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx

Comment: @sidnc86 I'm glad you solved the issue.